# chrome extension: jquery doesn't work on the new added item

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a simple function in my chrome extension, which user are allow to add specific button by clicking "add button", and remove the specific button they added by clicking the "delete button" on the popup.html.

User click on the delete button, and button is associate with "name = delete_'userNamedStock' ", which allow them to delete specific ones

But somehow when the user adds new button, the jquery remove function doesn't work?
I've tested in the console log, and it works properly, but everytime new item is added, the remove button stops responding.

Please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you!

stock.js to add and remove :

```
//detect search bar input 
$("button[name = 'add']").click(function () {
    var tickerSymbol = $("input[id = 'tickerInput']").val()
    $("input[id = 'tickerInput']").val(""); //reset textbox empty
    console.log(tickerSymbol);
    //add in new item 
    if (tickerSymbol != "") { //only add if user has input
        addTicker(tickerSymbol);
    }

});

//user delete stock
//wild card to get everything start from delete_

$("button[name^= 'delete_']").click(function(){

    DeleteTicker = this.name.replace("delete_","")
    console.log("delete: " + DeleteTicker );
    
    //remove from list
    tickerList = tickerList.filter(function(item){
        return item != DeleteTicker
    })
    console.log("newTicker list " + tickerList);

    //save new list
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ Inputlist: tickerList }, function () {
        console.log("tiker list stored " + tickerList); //update the list
    });

    //update html, remove the div 
    $("#" +DeleteTicker ).remove();
   
});
//all the functions 
//function to add ticker in storage space 
function addTicker(input) {
    if (!tickerList.includes(input)) { //only add if no item
        tickerList.push(input);

        chrome.storage.sync.set({ key: input, Inputlist: tickerList }, function () {
            console.log("tiker list stored " + tickerList); //update the list
        });

        chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function (result) {
            console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
            htmlStock(result.key); //write the html 
        });

    }
};

//function to display html 
function htmlStock(save_input) {
    $("#stockList").append(
        //div
        '<div class="btn-group dropleft" class = "stockItem"' +
        //set ticker symbol as div id
        'id=' + save_input + '>' +
            //ticker button 
            '<button  class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' +
        save_input + //display button text
            '</button>' +
            //delete button
            '<button class="btn btn-secondary delete" type="button"' + 
            'name = delete_'+ save_input + '>' + //name the delete button 
                '<i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>' +
            '</button>' +
            //dropdown menu
            '<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">' +
                '<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>' +
                '<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>' +
                '<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' 
    );
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Stocking",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Chrome extention",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons":{"128":"icon/icon128.png"},
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "<all_urls>",
      "storage"
    ],
    "browser_action":{
      "default_icon":{
        "16":"icon/icon16.png",
        "24":"icon/icon24.png",
        "32": "icon/icon32.png"},
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title":"real time tracker",
      "js": [
        "bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js",
        "bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      ],
      "css":[
        "bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap4.5.2.min.css"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: You've invented non-existent keys inside `browser_action` in manifest.json: `js` and `css`. Remove them and load these assets normally in your popup.html just like in any other html page. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: ohh, I didn't notice that! Thanks!